# How to run a function server-side with Node.js instead of browser-side with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, spotify

I am attempting to run a call to the Spotify API using the spotify-web-api-node package. To run certain API calls, I need to set my credentials using the function `spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()`. But whenever I call this function, from the script tag of my Vue application, it results in an Error: `Uncaught TypeError: spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant is not a function`.

According to [this issue on the spotify-web-api-node Github](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/issues/94), this is intended. They don't want people to set credentials using Javascript that is exposed to the client, and the request needs to be run server-side instead. So the spotify-web-api-node library only exposes this function when using the code from node.

While that explains why, I still don't really know how to fix the issue. How should I run the code from node? How can I move it out of exposed Javascript code so that I have access to the `clientCredentialsGrant` function? I'm not an experienced Node or Javascript developer so please explain in detail.

The code below is for the Vue component where I am running the calls to the Spotify API. The `Uncaught TypeError` comes from the promise `spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant().then()` at the beginning of the `<script>` tag.

```
<template>
  <section>
    <b-field>
      <button class="button is-light is-outlined is-large" @click="open">
        <p class="btn-txt">Calculate!</p>
      </button>
    </b-field>
    <b-loading :is-full-page="true" :active.sync="isLoading" :can-cancel="true"></b-loading>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import SpotifyWebApi from "spotify-web-api-node";

var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: "5fc39d2ee8144af88b66c4da4cf6a6a0",
  clientSecret: "a0722cde44f844289035b12279e26f41"
});

// Retrieve an access token.
console.log("The client ID is " + spotifyApi.getClientId());
console.log("The client secret is " + spotifyApi.getClientSecret());

spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant().then(
  function(data) {
    console.log("The access token expires in " + data.body["expires_in"]);
    console.log("The access token is " + data.body["access_token"]);

    // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body["access_token"]);
  },

  function(err) {
    console.log(
      "Something went wrong when retrieving an access token",
      err.message
    );
  }
);

// Get Elvis' albums
// Search tracks whose artist's name contains 'Kendrick Lamar', and track name contains 'Alright'
spotifyApi.searchTracks("track:Alright artist:Kendrick Lamar").then(
  function(data) {
    console.log(
      'Search tracks by "Alright" in the track name and "Kendrick Lamar" in the artist name',
      data.body
    );
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log("Something went wrong!", err);
  }
);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isFullPage: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    open() {
      const loadingComponent = this.$loading.open({
        container: this.isFullPage ? null : this.$refs.element.$el
      });
      setTimeout(() => loadingComponent.close(), 3 * 1000);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Also if it helps, here is the [Github repo for my little Vue web app](https://github.com/vintners/music-calc-app). The goal is to allow the user to enter a `song`, `artist`, and `time` in seconds, and then send a Search request to the Spotify web API to get back info about the song. This will give me the length of the song, and then I'll calculate how many times it's possible to listen to that song within the user-specified `time`.

**My key question**: how to run code from the server-side with Node.js? I don't know how to start here.

Comment: It really isn't clear what *specific* problem you are having. Have you written any Node.js code yet? Have you got any kind of web service running yet?

Comment: To elaborate on the comment above - is your frontend Vue application already running on node and you have access to it? Or is it 'just' a frontend and you wanted to apply a package that requires a server side node application running?

Comment: @Jeremy Please share code. But you know that this example should be divided into two parts? You generate the link and send the user there, and then (in the next routing) you obtain `code` from the request.

Comment: @quentin I haven't written any Node code and I'm not running a web service. This is meant to be a very simple single page app, I'm just using it to learn Vue. See above, I added more detail to my question.

Comment: @ErikReder Good questions. I created my Vue app with Vue-CLI (`vue create`), and I think that automatically sets up Vue to run on Node. I'm not sure though. So far, I haven't touched the Node.js code; I just want to apply a package that requires a Node application running. See above, I added more detail to my question.

Comment: @bato3 See above, I shared my code and added detail. In my case, I don't want the user to be involved at all. They don't need to login to Spotify or anything, and I shouldn't need to redirect them to another link. I'm using a client access token as the credential for the Spotify web API, and I want to handle all the API calls from the backend.

Comment: While I think that the question is a bit too wide spread, I'm trying to give some hints. First of all, try to search for things like 'node.js server side express sample' (I recommend the express framework, saves you quite some work initially). You'll get something like a app.js or server.js file in your app root which contains the server side code. You'll need to expose some (e.g. /callSpotifyAPI) and put the usage of the API in this place. From your frontend you will need to call this endpoint then (e.g. via an AJAX call). Hope this gives you a hand to search for your next steps...